# Setting kernel options for the i915

Tags: 16.04, kernel, intel, xps, i915

I am trying to configure the i915 driver on my XPS 13 (9360) running Ubuntu 16.04 for better battery runtime.

I have created a kernel config file with this name:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf
```

Content of the file:

```
options i915 modeset=1 enable_rc6=1 enable_fbc=1 enable_guc_loading=1 enable_guc_submission=1 enable_huc=1 enable_psr=1 disable_power_well=0
```

I have restarted the machine and checked the driver parameters with this:

```
systool -v -m i915
```

This doesn't list my options in the "Parameters" section.

Seems like my options are not set to the driver at all (only the "enable_hangcheck" option with its "Y" default value).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this command `update-initramfs -u -k all` I think it must help you.

Comment: May be try to add this to kernel parameters via grub in such form: `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1`.

Comment: Or try this instruction https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/linux-kernel-module-options-on-debian/

Comment: the systool cmd will report actual settings only if you type it as root (as lambda user, you get indeed only one parameter reported)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to regenerate the boot images with update-initramfs (thanks Denis).

For all kernels (if you have more than one installed)

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

For the currently used kernel (if you don't want to touch the others)

```
update-initramfs -u
```

After this, the options were set because I saw a boot-time error about "enable_huc" parameter being invalid (dmesg). However, systool still doesn't show the options.

Answer (score 1):

I created /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf, see also

man intel

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

And now I have a decent background.